# How to use UserManager<IdentityUser> with UserStore<IdentityUser>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

this is a snippet of my ASP.Net MVC Core project.

```
UserStore<IdentityUser> userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>(_db);
UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
```

I am receiving the error message below from UserManager's parameter input.

[image]

I've tried changing userStore's data type to IUserStore and var, but they result in the same errors. Please help!

Comment: You need to specify the rest of the parameters of your UserManager. So: new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore, optionsAccessor, passwordhasher, uservalidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore,null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```